# error in running selenium (chrome driver) on GCE?

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run chrome browser for selenium purposes on GCE (Google compute engine) but the error I am receiving is:

```
ERROR: 
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64 x86_64)
```

I've tried installing google chrome and chromium driver of 2.26. on GCE. Already added the arguments of --headless, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --no-sandbox etc. in python code but the error remains constant.

```py
FOR INSTALLING ! ! !
sudo apt-get install libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt-get install xvfb

sudo apt-get install unzip

wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.26/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

```
# PYTHON CODE FOR PERFORMING SELENIUM TASKS #
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("-disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/dev_baseh/finalpdf/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.investorslounge.com/stock-market/index-history')
```

My question is, when I am sending the correct path of chrome driver, google chrome is also installed at GCE, and with the extension that it runs headlessly as installing xvfb does this thing, why it is giving me error?

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

Firstly, try to use `ChromeOptions()` instead of `Options()`. Also in Linux I think you need first to start the display.
Try the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1080))  
display.start()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("-disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/dev_baseh/finalpdf/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.investorslounge.com/stock-market/index-history')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am using Linux system and my GCE is also running over linux system, so I've downloaded chrome driver for Linux and can't add ".exe" extension. In linux, there is not extension! please guide. 

I've imported : 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

that's why I'd used Options() instead of  webdriver.ChromeOptions(), 

anyways, I've changed as per your say.

Comment: I've applied this Display version before, it gives me error that value is not found, error is: 

ERROR
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64 x86_64)

that's why I added the argument "--window-size=1920x1080"

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, when I am sending the correct path of chrome driver ...

One comment about Chrome and its path... I found Chrome moves around a lot depending on the distro and version.

This is what a piece of my code looks like. It works fairly well on Armbian, Debian, Fedora and Ubuntu.

```python
def get_chrome():
    if os.path.isfile('/usr/bin/chromium-browser'):
        return '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
    elif os.path.isfile('/usr/bin/chromium'):
        return '/usr/bin/chromium'
    elif os.path.isfile('/usr/bin/chrome'):
        return '/usr/bin/chrome'
    elif os.path.isfile('/usr/bin/google-chrome'):
        return '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
    else:
        return None
```

And then:

```python
opts = Options()
opts.binary_location = get_chrome()
opts.add_argument('--headless')
opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
opts.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
```

I don't use Amazon or Google clouds, so I don't know what Amazon or Google are doing in their clouds or with their images. I expect `get_chrome()` would work unless it is an unusual configuration.